# What is the recipe mod that "the diamond minecart" and "syndicate" use?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, mod-identification

What is the recipe mod that "the diamond minecart" and "syndicate" use? It is on the right of the picture listed.

[image: the mod is on the right. (the "recipe" viewer)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That mod is called TMI or Too Many Items. It allows you to look up recipes and spawn items.

Comment: thank you very much for your help but i found out it was not enough items, but thanks anyways!

Comment: TMI is outdated, always use NEI

Comment: @EliasBenevedes Both are updated to 1.7.10 and, from what I can see, TMI is usually updated faster.

Comment: The reason TMI is updated faster is because it has less features than NEI... like I said before, ALWAYS use NEI.

Answer (score 0):

It's called Too Many Items, but that's outdated. Use Not Enough Items. Search NEI on google or any search engine. I prefer google